# Parsing figure name on Beautiful Soup

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

This is my first time posting, so please be gentle.
I'm extracting data from trip advisor. The reviews are interpreted with a figure that is represented like this.

```
<span class="ui_bubble_rating bubble_40"></span>
```

As you can see, there is a "40" in the end that represents 4 stars. The same happens with "20" (2 stars) etc...

How can I obtain the "ui_bubble_rating bubble_40"?
Thank you in advance...

Comment: Welcome to SO. Your question is unclear. What do you mean by *obtain the "ui_bubble_rating bubble_40"*? Please consider to visit the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help) especially the ["How do I ask a good question?"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) section

Comment: What I mean by the  "ui_bubble_rating bubble_40" is literally, how do I get that string. I wish to append it to a list so that I can assign a corresponding value depending on its final number, but I do not know how to get the string itself.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is the most efficient way of doing that, but here's how I'd do it:

```
tags = soup.find_all(class=re.compile("bubble_\d\d"))
```

The `tags` variable will then include every tag in the page that matches the regex `bubble_\d\d`. After that, you just need to extract the number, like so:

```
stars = tags[0].split("_")[1]
```

If you want to be fancy, you can use list comprehensions to extract the numbers from every tag:

```
stars = [tag.split("_")[1] for tag in tags]
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what kind of data you are trying to scrape,
but you can obtain that span tag like so (I tested it and left some prints in):

```
from urllib import urlopen
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re

html = urlopen("YOUR_REVIEWS_URL")
bs1=BeautifulSoup(html, 'lxml')

for s in bs1.findAll("span", {"class":"ui_bubble_rating bubble_40"}):
        print(s)
```

More generic way (scrape all ratings (bubble_[0-9]{2})):

```
toFind = re.compile("(bubble_[0-9]{2})+")
for s in bs1.findAll("span", {"class":toFind}):
        print(s)
```

Hope that answers your question

Comment: Thank you both! I managed to resolve my problem. This is a great community. Thanks for the help!